# Change layout_height of Linearlayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am a beginner at Android. I have some troubles. I create list with names,surnames and phones something like address book, which contain and a toggle button, which suppose its increase the height of each cell which contains all the info like name,phone etc... But nothing happen. My code is below:

This is my `fragmentlayout.xml`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</ListView>
```

This is my `rowlayout.xml`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my main

```
 package com.example.serepasf.my_app2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;


    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragmentlayout);
           ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
           toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
                        l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,320));
                        // The toggle is enabled
                    } else {
                        // The toggle is disabled
                    }
                }
            });
            LstFragment lstfragment=(LstFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment");
            if(lstfragment==null){
                lstfragment=new LstFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transact.add(android.R.id.content,lstfragment,"lstfragment");
                transact.commit();

            }
        }

    }
```

So I want to change the height and width of Linear layout,lay which is in `rowlayout.xml`
Thanks

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.lay);`? This doesn't exist anymore after you do `transact.add(android.R.id.content,lstfragment`... Why do you need a Fragment if you just replace the entire Activity with it?

Comment: Have you tried 'l.invalidate()' after you set the layout params?

Comment: I have also the class LstFragment which help me to read a csv with all the info which I need and parse it to the rows of my list.

Comment: No , I haven't try l.invalidate().. I just try nothing happening but in logs ,when I click first time the toggle appear these messages `W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@2d9bf35[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
`

Answer (score 0):

why did you write `android:layout_height="60dp"` if you want it to extend based on content than why not make it `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but then the layout won't be consistent

Comment: Somewhere I read that if I set android:layout_height="wrap_content" next I cant change the height.. but at first I have it like that a nothing seems to happening